# Error encountered while creating mamba package

Tags: python-bob

I am very new to mamba, but I would like to use it to access the bob interface for the UTFVP database. When I try follow the installation tutorial from their website, I receive an error at step 3. This step requires you to run the following command:

- mamba create --name bob_env1 --override-channels -c https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/conda -c conda-forge   python=3 bob.db.utfvp

, where bob.db.utfvp is the specific package I want to access. The error I receive is the following:

- Encountered problems while solving:
  nothing provides libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 needed by bob.io.base-3.0.3-py27hf5c1720_0

I have used "conda install libblitz" to install libblitz 1.0.2, this did not solve the issue.
I hope somebody can help me, thank in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should do to solve the issue.
Run this command below on a linux-64 Operating system

1. conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 libblitz
   or rather choose any of the two options written below.
2. conda install -c conda-forge libblitz
3. conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 libblitz

more details could be found at the official anaconda's website written below.
https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/libblitz

Furthermore, install  the bob.learn.libsvm

usin conda install bob.learn.libsvm. more details on installation is found on the github repository https://github.com/bioidiap/bob.learn.libsvm

Answer (score 0):

Try using the archive channel.

mamba create --name env_name --override-channels 
-c https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/conda -c https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/conda/label/archive 
bob.package-name